# Unable to run bundle install command

Tags: ruby

Everytime when I run bundle install, I get this error. But actually my network is fine too.

```
B:\aptana workspace\File ish\aut1>bundle install

DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Network error while fetching http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/paperclip-ffmpeg-1.0.1.gemspec.rz
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please show you `Gemfile`.

Comment: If you try to access `http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/paperclip-ffmpeg-1.0.1.gemspec.rz` does it work? Check any proxy.

Answer (score -2):

Update your `Gemfile` and write this link on top of the page:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

Make sure that you use `https://` protocol. Using `http://` considering unsafe.